# MongoDB: can't return random document from collection

Tags: mongodb, function, express, random, controller

I'm working on a word game and am trying to return a random *wordpair* (my collection) on a page load. I'm using Express and have adapted my code from [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose) if that's of any use.

A GET request renders my page just fine, and I'm trying to send a random WordPair object alongside the title:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('play', { title: 'play', random_wordpair: wordpair_controller.wordpair_random});
});
```

The wordpair_random function is here inside a controller file I've made (which also successfully manages listing the wordpairs and creating new ones etc).

```
// Get random WordPair
exports.wordpair_random = function() {
   WordPair.aggregate(
      [{
        $sample: {
          size: 1
        }
      }]
    )
    .exec(function(err, random_wordpair) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      console.log(random_wordpair);
      return random_wordpair;
    });
};
```

Then inside a play.pug template, I'm simply trying to display this result:

```
h3 random wordpair selection is: #{random_wordpair}
```

But all I can see is the function rendered as HTML text. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I also understand looking at the documentation for MongoDB [$sample aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample) that I need to be calling my function on the database object, but I've seen various examples and some don't do this. When I try calling `db.wordpair.aggregate(...)` (or *WordPair* or *wordpairs* as it appears in mLab) directly after initializing `db` in my `app.js` file, I get undefined errors. My `db` object doesn't seem to contain the correct data for this request.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're writing this in Node.JS. A core feature in Node.JS is non-blocking IO model. That means, the code won't wait for a database call to complete to move on.

Another concept you need to get it right is that Node.JS, being a variation of JavaScript, in nature is a functional programming. Assigning a function to a property of a JSON object like below won't cause the function to execute. It simply creates a pointer to the function body, that's why your application prints the function itself.

```
{ title: 'play', random_wordpair: wordpair_controller.wordpair_random}
```

To fix this, use a callback

```
exports.wordpair_random = function(callback) {
    WordPair.aggregate([$sample: {size: 1}}]).exec(callback);
};
```

Then in you web function:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    wordpair_controller.wordpair_random(function(err, result) {
        //Handle errors if needed. 
        res.render('play', { title: 'play', random_wordpair:result });
    })
});
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for explaining and not just giving an answer!